# Unable to get value from function in Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to get the value from the function which contains 2 values, one is pointed from the current method, and another value is `null`.

What I expect is to print out the `$convertAccountEx` value from the function, but it gives me nothing. I have tried to give `$null` value for `$convertAccountEx`, but nothing changes.

```
function ConvertTo-Date(){

        Param ($accountEx,$convertAccountEx)

        if($accountEx.accountExpires -eq 0){
                $convertAccountEx = "Never"
            }
        else{
                $convertAccountEx = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($AccountEx.accountExpires)                
        }

}

$userObjects = $ADSearch.FindAll()

foreach ($user  in $userObjects){

         $accountEx = $user.Properties.Item("accountExpires")
         ConvertTo-Date -accountEx $accountEx.accountExpires -convertAccountEx $convertAccountEx

         $convertAccountEx
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should look like this:

```
function ConvertTo-Date(){

        Param ($accountEx)

        if($accountEx.accountExpires -eq 0){
                $convertAccountEx = "Never"
            }
        else{
                $convertAccountEx = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($AccountEx.accountExpires)                
        }

        $convertAccountEx

}

$userObjects = $ADSearch.FindAll()

foreach ($user  in $userObjects){

        $accountEx = $user.Properties.Item("accountExpires")
        ConvertTo-Date -accountEx $accountEx.accountExpires

}
```

The issue you ran into is called scoping. The idea is, that every variable you create, should be exclusive to its running scope. So the var inside your function is  - by definition - a different var than outside, even if they share the name. An easy way to go around this in your example is, to just return the value from you function (by calling it).

What I would advise is: Don't just return the value, but append it to the objects you create. Here a (really) simple example:

```
function Add-Info {
    Param( $user )
    $user | Add-Member -NotePropertyName NewProperty -NotePropertyValue 'SomeValue'
    $user
}
```

Comment: Thank so much for your solid answer. I have tried to get it inside the function and got the result as well. But it wasn't my idea. Hmm, I will think about this further.

Comment: u can use `$Global:convertAccountEx`  and then it will be available globally

Comment: Technically true, but I would categorize this as bad coding.

Comment: @restless1987 Hi, tks for your respond. I really appreciate that if you can explain why it's considered is a bad coding?. Waiting for your reply.

Comment: @Ender : you rely on things that might not be in your possession, or responsibility. Of course, you could just overwrite what already is there as variable. But you might break something. You as person are responsible for your code. Don't get that messy by scoping out, without needing to. If you want, I can expand this a bit.